# Wordpress multisite: wp-admin 403 error

Tags: multisite

I want to use wordpress multisite. So I add code to wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/multi/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Also I have added code to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /multi/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) D:/localhost/Multi/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ D:localhost/Multi/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Also I have created second website - multi/second And I can see frontend of second website ( posts / images ... )

but when I try to use admin panel - multi/second/wp-admin I get

```
You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you install WordPress on a subdirectory (/multi) and on localhost? Can you log in the main site admin: /multi/wp-admin?

The error is to do with "permission to access the requested directory", it's probably not to do with WordPress settings/config.

Check your WP installation again for potential missing steps (which might cause the permission issue) with this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-debian
and this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-debian-7
(I do exactly as the guide and don't have any error when activate multisite, WP4.7 on Debian 8.6)